# Get number of lines of all the functions in a repository

Tags: php, git, file

I need to list all the files present in the repository with their number of line of code.
I managed to do it with a git command

```
git ls-files | xargs wc -l
```

Now i also need list of all the functions in the repository and number of lines of the function. I got the function names by using:

```
grep -R function
```

But i'm not able to find any way to get the number of lines for the functions.

Can anyone help me with this, or suggest any tool that i can use..??

FYI, i'm using a linux OS.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you take a look to `cloc`  ?

Comment: Using Git for this is like using your storage shed to see how long your garden hoses are. It's the wrong tool. Just use the storage shed (er, Git) to hold the hoses (er, commits containing files). As Ôrel suggested, [cloc](https://github.com/AlDanial/cloc) is probably the right tool here.

Comment: I've tried to use cloc, but i couldn't find a way to list the function names and their count of number of lines of code.